# 'module' object have no attribute

Tags: python-2.7

I have been searching this site and googling around to find a problem similar and of course a solution for that. But no success.
My problem is:- 
Each time when I try to run my python module (any .py file) using CMD python OR simply by double click. I am getting the Attribute Error as you can see in the picture.
Link to the picture as I couldn't post the picture due to 10 reputation limitation.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BztaImknhgDFdzhZVXBWWk45MGs/view?usp=sharing

one thing, I want to mention here is that I have installed python many a time with in a period of 3 days to suit my project needs.

Solutions I have tried:-
1. I have re-installed my Python to a new directory.
2. Rebooted many times.

My Current Python version 2.7.9 64bit, Pyscripter 64 bit and windows 7 64bit.

Any help would be appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved!
I was missing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

statement.